# Rails Create Related Models together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Models `Order(id, user_id,...)` and `OrderEvent(id, order_id, ...)`the data of these are stored in two Objects `@order` and `@order_event`.

> Now i want to save Order and update the order_id in OrderEvent and
>   then save the content in the database.

In CakePHP if we had the content structured in a certain way we could save all of these together at once. Is there a way to save the content in a single call so that if there is any validation error both records are not created and fails

Order

```
--- !ruby/object:Order
attributes:
  id: 
  host_id: 1
  user_id: 1
  order_no: PH1504-F3D11353
  type_of_order: events
  order_date: !ruby/object:DateTime 2015-04-17 10:49:52.066168000 Z
  sub_total: 7050.0
  tax_rate: 
  rate_cost: 
  deliver_charges: 
  discount_code: 
  discount_rate: 
  discount_cost: 
  total_cost: 7050.0
  order_dishes_count: 
  order_events_count: 
  status: 0
  created_at: 
  updated_at:
```

OrderEvent

```
--- !ruby/object:OrderEvent
attributes:
  id: 
  order_id: 
  event_id: 2
  no_of_ppl: 3
  event_date: 2015-01-22 00:00:00.000000000 Z
  cost: 2350.0
  total_cost: 7050.0
  status: 0
  created_at: 
  updated_at:
```

Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :host

  has_many :order_events
  has_many :messages

end
```

OrderEvent

```
class OrderEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: Post code of related model code. BTW, you seems very beginner in RoR, this is 3rd question I am seeing from you within an hour :D:D:D

Comment: yeah. moving from php to rails :P @RAJ migrating the app :( learning on the go :P and troubling u guys

Comment: @RAJ posted the data

Comment: By 'model code', I meant code of class Order & OrderEvent

Comment: @RAJ posted :) the class

Comment: And what has this to do with CakePHP? I removed that pointless tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set proper associations, following will work for you:

```
@order = Order.create(...)
@order_event = @order.order_events.create(...) # pass all attrs except id & order_id
```

**EDIT:**

> If I have the object ready and just wanna save can I use '.save' instead of .create –  Harsha M V

In that case, you can directly update `@order_event` as:

```
@order_event.update(:order => @order)
```

Comment: if i have the object ready and just wanna save can i use '.save' instead of .create

Comment: This is not ideal condition, however, yes you can survive in that condition too. Check out my update in answer.

Comment: can we pass an object that was created @order = Order.new() into Order.create(@order)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: i wanna create an Order which has details of Which event was ordered. Order is a single record that will have the base info where as the secondary table will have info about the event. This is done because an order eventually can have more events in a single order

Comment: i have  [at]order = Order.new(params) [at]order_event = OrderEvent.new(params) and the data is ready in [at]order and [at]order_event only thing thats not filled is the order_id in [at]order_event which we will get only when we save [at]order and its ID is saved at order_id in [at]order_event

Comment: `@order_event = @order.order_events.create(...) `  will create order_event for @order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75498/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-raj).

Answer (score 2):

Inverse_of and accepts_nested_attributes_for allow you to create two associated objects at the same time. 
Your models should be something like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :order_events, inverse_of: :order

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_events

end

class OrderEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :order_event
end
```

In the orders controller:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.order_events.build
end

def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  ...
end
```

Allow order_events attributes in the params:

```
def order_params
   params.require(:order).permit(order_event_attributes: [])
end
```

In the form:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :order_events do |event| %>
  <!-- event fields go here -->
<% end %>
```

Here is an article with more details what invese_of does: http://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for might be :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

If you only want to update the OrderEvent just do

```
class OrderEvent
  belongs_to :order
end
```

And in your controller

```
@order_event.update_attributes(order: @order)
```

Edit : update_attributes saves to the database.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update for more info.

If you have both models ready but none has an id yet then I think you should go for nested attributes :

```
class Order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_events
  has_many :order_events
end

class OrderEvent
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I controller, In order to save the Order, with its order_events :

```
def update
  @order.update_attributes(order_events_attributes: [@order_event])
end
```

Should work like a charm.

Comment: can u share on how to save into the database

Comment: i mean i have done [at]order = Order.new(params) [at]order_event = OrderEvent.new(params) and the data is ready in [at]order and [at]order_event only thing thats not filled is the order_id in [at]order_event which we will get only when we save [at]order and its ID is saved at order_id in [at]order_event

Comment: sorry had to use [at] since it wouldnt allow be to use @

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use Transactions of rails. Reference : [Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)